# Where should my Selenium tests check for expected/actual results?

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently designing a testing framework for a web application. The framework is a hybrid (data and keyword driven) framework. I have it set up so I have packages full of UI functions who's methods I can call into test classes to navigate and click the application.

I'm wondering about best practices.

Should I be checking for results with every step I take? Or should I check results at the end of the test?

For more detail, this is the current structure of my test with minimized code:

```
// This test contains one step. The following method navigates to the page and inputs invalid credentials.
// We than check if we're still on the login page. If we are, the test passes. If we can't find the
// "login text", than the test has failed.
        LoginPage.invalidCredentialsOne.run(driver);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement logintext = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("logintext")));
        if (logintext.getText().equals("LOG IN")) {
            //add pass entry to the excel sheet
            testresultdata.put("3", new Object[] {
                2d, "User should not be able to login with an invalid password", "Login failed", "Pass"
            });
            driver.close();
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
        } else {
            //add fail entry to the excel sheet
            testresultdata.put("3", new Object[] {
                2d, "User should not be able to login with an invalid password", "Login failed", "Fail"
            });
            fail();
            driver.close();
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
        }
```

In the above code, I check for expected/actual results *AFTER* I have ran the method. Would it be advisable to check the expected/actual results inside the method itself? What would the pros/cons of this be?

I feel as though running the expected/actual results in the method would improve maintainability as well as test accuracy (being able to see exactly where your test failed).

Or why not just test through both?

Methods - Check every navigation made. If the navigation failed, output a line in the console telling you where. This checks for simple UI bugs.

Test classes - Check for more specific user scenarios.

Very interested in the proper best practices to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide the test approach (especially with the system tests written in selenium) to Action and Verification. This means that you have to divide the methods that lead to some system changing (like yours `invalidCredentialsOne`) and methods that should verify/test the system state after the changes took place.

Why this is good? In this way you may build your user scenarios with help some set of actions and verify this set in the required place. This approach provides flexibility for building various scenarios and verios tests.

If we back to your example let's assume that you want to test not only that you back to the login page in case the wrong credentials but, for example, that after 5 tries the system (just assume that!) will block the user.
In this case you may to use your first action 5 times and then verify if the system blocks the user.

P.S. Please try to avoid using `Thread.sleep` in your selenium code. The waiting for the object appearance much better.

Comment: So you'd agree that we can use the test classes themselves to check more specific scenarios, while we can use the methods to check user interface?  Also, for the `Thread.sleep`, would a proper replacement look something like `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);` and than `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("logintext"))));`?

Comment: Yes - for the first I mostly talked for the UI test - selenium,  and yes for the second     :)

Comment: @jagdpanzer please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, thanks